# Is there a way to display html element "progress" on a html5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a `canvas` in `HTML5` and a progress element

```
<canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="900">Canvas</canvas>
<progress id="health" value="100" max="100" hidden="true"></progress>
```

I was wondering if it is possible to draw or display the progress element onto the canvas using `JavaScript` or some other method.

Thank you.

Comment: DOM elements do not go inside a canvas tag. Canvas is for drawing, not for displaying DOM elements. You'll need to create a progress bar made for Canvas.

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

You could also keep a DOM element and use CSS to position it on top of the canvas.

It wouldn't exactly be a part of the canvas, but 'position: absolute;' plus setting top and left styles could move that on top of the canvas.

EDIT: Fixed a typo

Comment: i was gonna suggest this. it's super easy and probably won't cause any issues.

Comment: @Jakub If this worked for you please set as the correct answer.